# See if the email exists or not

Tags: custom-post-types, php, wpdb, email, wp-insert-post

I have extracted a bunch of emails using PHP IMAP connection and assigned those emails to a custom post type. Here's the code how I assigned those emails to custom post type.

```
    $total =  $emails->total_msg(); 
    for ($j=1; $j <= $total; $j++) { 
       $mail =  $emails->get($j);
       $post_array = array( 
        'post_content'  => $mail['body'],
        'post_title'    => $mail['header']->subject,
        'post_type'     => 'my-custom-post-type',
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'meta_input'    => array(
            'from'      => $mail['header']->fromaddress,
            'email_date'=> $mail['header']->Date,   // add post meta as many as you want
            'ticket_id' => $mail['header']->message_id,
            ),
       );
       wp_insert_post($post_array);
    }
```

Now, `$emails` is where I stored all the emails.
I want to do a simple check that if the emails already exist do not do `wp_insert_post()` and if the email does not exist then only do `wp_insert_post`.
I don't much about logic and how to do it. If someone can do it. It will be a big help.

Comment: @Rohic : Hi. I'm not sure I fully understand your problem. You only want to add the email if it doesn't already exist. What makes an email unique? `body + subject + fromaffress + date + message_id`? just `message_id`?

Comment: @Rohic : So, you need to create a function that returns true or false with the fields that make a post unique as parameters. This function will be used in the condition you wish to set up before the insertion. In this function, you need to do a simple query to retrieve the post with these field values. If a post is found, the function returns true, so no insert, otherwise the function returns false and you can do the `wp_insert_post`

Comment: For now just `message_id` is what  I need to check if it already exists.

Comment: yes, that's kind of what I am trying to do. but I just don't know how to get started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to create the following function:

```
function checkEmailAlreadyExists( $message_id ) {
    $posts_with_meta = get_posts( array(
        'posts_per_page' => 1, // we only want to check if any exists, so don't need to get all of them
        'post_type'      => 'my-custom-post-type',
        'meta_key'       => 'ticket_id',
        'meta_value'     => $message_id,
        'fields'         => 'ids', // we don't need it's content, etc.
    ) );

    return ( count( $posts_with_meta ) ) ? true : false;    
}
```

Now you just have to add it to your current code:

```
$total = $emails->total_msg(); 
for ( $j=1; $j <= $total; $j++ ) {
    $mail = $emails->get( $j );
    if ( !empty( $mail['header']->message_id ) && !checkEmailAlreadyExists( $mail['header']->message_id )  ) {
        $post_array = array( 
            'post_content'  => $mail['body'],
            'post_title'    => $mail['header']->subject,
            'post_type'     => 'my-custom-post-type',
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
            'meta_input'    => array(
                'from'       => $mail['header']->fromaddress,
                'email_date' => $mail['header']->Date,
                'ticket_id'  => $mail['header']->message_id,
            ),
        );
        wp_insert_post( $post_array );
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not quite working, as every time I refresh same emails are being inserted repeatedly.

Comment: @Rohic : I added the post_type parameter to the « check »  function. Can you try doing a: `$test = checkEmailAlreadyExists(XXX);` replacing XXX with an existing DB message_id and then a `var_dump($test);`

Comment: For every message_id it is giving false.

Comment: I just tested on one of my sites, I did it with the post_type: `post` and it works perfectly. Did you add the post_type in the `checkEmailAlreadyExists` function?

Comment: Yes, I added my post type in `checkEmailAlreadyExist` but nothing happend.

Comment: @Rohic : Ok we can try to debug, I'll write that in another answer to this topic which I'll delete after.

Comment: @Rohic : My condition was misplaced. It should be after the $mail declaration.

Comment: You mean `checkEmailAlreadyExist`  should be after `$mail` declaration.

Comment: @Rohic : Exactly, since we use $mail in our test function.  (The call of the function not the declaration)

Comment: Nothing seems to work on my end.

Comment: I am absolutely certain that the verification function is correct. Maybe the problem is elsewhere. That being said, it's a bit strange that the post_inserts are made when every page on the site loads...